# Install MySQL workbench on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, mysql

I am using **Ubuntu 9.10 - the Karmic Koala** - released in October 2009

I downloaded **mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1004-i386.deb** from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads)

But when I run this package it show me following error:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.29.3)
```

How can I install MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like 5.1.19 and 5.0.30 are available from the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to either upgrade libatk or find an older version of MySQL Workbench.  Sometimes there are newer packages in the backports repository, but I checked karmic-backports in [Ubuntu's Package Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and a newer version has not been backported.  Ubuntu 10.04+ does have a newer version of libatk that's compatible with MySQL Workbench.  You could try installing on 9.10 ignoring dependencies and hope it works anyways.

```
dpkg --ignore-depends=libatk1.0 -i mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1004-i386.deb
```

The only other option is to download the source from 10.04 Maverick and recompile it on Karmic.  Get the source from http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/maverick/atk1.0.  You will need the .dsc, .diff.gz, and .tar.gz file from that page.

```
wget 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atk1.0/atk1.0_1.32.0-0ubuntu1.dsc'
wget 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atk1.0/atk1.0_1.32.0.orig.tar.gz'
wget 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atk1.0/atk1.0_1.32.0-0ubuntu1.diff.gz
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
dpkg-source -x atk1.0_1.32.0-0ubuntu1.dsc
cd atk1.0-1.32.0
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Once it's done building, you will have a number of .deb files in the parent directory.  You will need to install any over what's already installed.